# Good programming puzzle requiring a lot of conditional logic?

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

What is a classic programming puzzle which will require a lot of conditional logic and branches to solve?

Thanks

Comment: And the connection between the title and your question is ?

Comment: Sorry, I had restarted my browser, saw the contents of the form with the post I wanted to ask but it had an old title.

Comment: You could solve Go [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)] ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eight queens and Towers of Hanoi are classics. Solving Sudoku is quite interesting too and is really a graph coloring problem in disguise.

Comment: where is conditional statements in **Hanoi** problem? it can be wrote without `if`

Answer (score 3):

I like the problem of writing a function that computes the least number of multiplications to compute x^N (e.g., for N = 30, you can compute x^N with 6 multiplies - x -> x^2 - > x^3 -> x^5 -> x^10 -> x^15 -> x^30.

There's no known efficient algorithm, so you have to use branch-and-bound.  The conditional logic and branching come in when you are trying to bound. See this wikipedia article for more details - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain

Answer (score 2):

[Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://codingbat.com/) are a lot of small programming puzzles. a Lot of them are about logic

Comment: Project Euler has lots of stuff too.

Answer (score 2):

If the purpose is for an interview (i.e. you need to have a candidate bang out some code as part of the evaluation process), I've always liked [Project Euler question 11](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=11).

If it's for your own use to learn a new language, etc. I prefer some of the code kata at [codingdojo.org](http://codingdojo.org/) (the OCR one is pretty entertaining in any language).